# What does"'vi' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." mean?

Tags: editor, email-client

While sending a mail using mutt in windows I got the error saying:
**'vi' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**
How to debug that error.
I have already installed Cygwin with the VI editor package.But it doesn't seem to be working!!

Answer (score 2):

This error message generally means the *vi* executable file was not found in any of the folder locations defined in the **PATH** environment variable.

To fix this find the folder location of the *vi* executable file and add it to the [PATH](http://www.zeusedit.com/zforum/viewtopic.php?p=8675).

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, your PATH environment variable is missing "C:\cygwin\bin" directory, but this answer assumes you accepted the Cygwin installation default location.  If you can not find the problem, simply re-install Cygwin to the same location on disk and then carefully review all of the questions asked before accepting defaults.

The Title of this question omits Cygwin, so Google treats it like a generic vi pathing issue, sending Powershell users to this page as well.

If you just want VI working in Powershell, I don't suggest Cygwin these days.  Instead:

1. Install Chocolatey https://chocolatey.org/install
2. Open Powershell AS Administrator
3. chocolatey.exe install vim

Technically Chocolatey is not required - you could get vim from the vim website. But chocolatey will make easier work of the install, including offering other UNIX utilities.